# how can I combine two different gdb commands “info symbol” and “ptype” into single one？

Tags: nginx, gdb, symbols

in other words，Is there a command that can find the symbol at an address meanwhile use ptype show this symbol‘s detail info ？
or if there is not， how can i write a user-define command meet this needs ？

for example， now i can firstly get data struct‘s name (ngx_errlog_module_ctx) in a address use “info symbol” command， than use ptype show the data struct’s detail info like this：

```
(gdb) info symbol 0x80b4568
ngx_errlog_module_ctx in section .data of /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx

(gdb) ptype ngx_errlog_module_ctx
type = struct {
    ngx_str_t name;
    void *(*create_conf)(ngx_cycle_t *);
    char *(*init_conf)(ngx_cycle_t *, void *);
}
```

but now， how can i write a user-difined command (ptype_with_address) that i can use like this :

```
ptype_with_address 0x80b4568

ngx_errlog_module_ctx in section .data of /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
type = struct {
ngx_str_t name;
    void *(*create_conf)(ngx_cycle_t *);
    char *(*init_conf)(ngx_cycle_t *, void *);
}
```

i want to do this because i am research nginx’s code，i want write a user-defined command to show all ngx_modules's detail info, include each module's ctx member variable.

Answer (score 0):

> can i write a user-define command meet this need

If you have a reasonably recent version of GDB, you should be able to use built-in Python interpreter to achieve your goal.

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like you can get the `gdb.Symbol` from its address, you [need the symbol name](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Symbols-In-Python.html#Symbols-In-Python). In other words, it doesn't look like `info symbol` is currently exposed to Python interpreter in GDB.

I suggest filing a feature request in [bugzilla](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gdb) to extend `gdb.lookup_global_symbol` to also accept an address.

Googling for "gdb python info symbol" revealed this [thread](http://old.nabble.com/%27info-symbol%27-equivalent-in-python--td33526400.html), in which Tom Tromey (gdb developer) also asked to file a bugzilla issue, and suggested a workaround.